# How can I avoid org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Original error: socket hang up?

Tags: java, android, webdriver, appium

I am running a test automation suite using Appium 2.2.1, Java 11, TestNG, and Cucumber.
I keep running into a problem where I get `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up` in the middle of a test execution. This usual also fouls up the next couple of scenarios.

I know the usual way to solve this is to run `adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test` and `adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server`, but how can I set up my code to avoid this error all together.

Here is how I am running my tests on real devices. Note: The above error throws even when I am just running a single Thread, on one device.

RunParallelTest.java

```java
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "classpath:features",
        glue = {"stepdefs"}
)
public class RunParallelTests extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    private final DesiredCapabilitiesUtil desiredCapabilitiesUtil = new DesiredCapabilitiesUtil();
    private final AppiumServiceBuilderUtil appiumServiceBuilderUtil = new AppiumServiceBuilderUtil();
    protected AppiumDriverLocalService service;

    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void startAppiumServer(){
        //System.out.println("Building Appium Server");
        service = appiumServiceBuilderUtil.buildAppiumService();
        System.out.println("Starting Appium Server");
        service.clearOutPutStreams();
        service.start();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters({"deviceOS"})
    public void setup(String deviceOS){
        service.isRunning();
        URL serviceURL = service.getUrl();
        switch (deviceOS) {
            case "iOS":
                //System.out.println("Initializing iOS Driver");
                DesiredCapabilities iosCaps = desiredCapabilitiesUtil.getDesiredCapabilities(deviceOS);
                ThreadLocalDriver.setTLDriver(new IOSDriver(serviceURL, iosCaps));
                break;
            case "Android":
                //System.out.println("Initializing Android Driver");
                DesiredCapabilities androidCaps = desiredCapabilitiesUtil.getDesiredCapabilities(deviceOS);
                ThreadLocalDriver.setTLDriver(new AndroidDriver(serviceURL, androidCaps));
                if (((AndroidDriver)ThreadLocalDriver.getTLDriver()).isDeviceLocked()){
                    ((AndroidDriver)ThreadLocalDriver.getTLDriver()).unlockDevice();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public synchronized void teardown() {
        ThreadLocalDriver.getTLDriver().quit();
    }

    @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public synchronized void stopAppiumServer(){
        if(service.isRunning()) {
            System.out.println("Stopping Appium Server");
            service.stop();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Appium Server Already Closed");
        }
    }

}
```

AppiumServiceBuilderUtil.java

```java
public class AppiumServiceBuilderUtil {

    public AppiumServiceBuilderUtil(){}

    private static final ThreadLocal<AppiumDriverLocalService> tlService = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public static synchronized void setTLService(AppiumDriverLocalService service) { tlService.set(service); }
    public static synchronized AppiumDriverLocalService getTLService() {
        return tlService.get();
    }

    public AppiumDriverLocalService buildAppiumService(){
        String serverOS = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("deviceOS");
        AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();

/* Deprecated, Now uses default values
        builder.withIPAddress("0.0.0.0");
        builder.usingPort(4723);
*/
        builder.usingAnyFreePort();
        builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.USE_PLUGINS, "relaxed-caps");
        builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.ALLOW_INSECURE, "chromedriver_autodownload");
        
        builder.usingDriverExecutable(new File("/opt/homebrew/bin/node"));

        builder.withLogFile(new File(String.format("logs/appium_server_log_%s.log", serverOS)));
        setTLService(AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder));
        return getTLService();

    }

}
```

DesiredCapabilitiesUtil.java

```java
public class DesiredCapabilitiesUtil {
    private static final ThreadLocal<DesiredCapabilities> tlCaps = new ThreadLocal<>();
    static Properties props = new Properties();

    public DesiredCapabilitiesUtil(){}

    public static synchronized void setTlCaps(DesiredCapabilities caps){tlCaps.set(caps);}

    public static synchronized DesiredCapabilities getTLCaps() {
        return tlCaps.get();
    }

    public DesiredCapabilities getDesiredCapabilities(String deviceOS){
        boolean localRun = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("localRun", "false"));
        String capFile;
        if(localRun){
            capFile = "local-decivecapabilities.properties";}
        else {
            capFile = "decivecapabilities.properties";}

        try (InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(capFile)){
            props.load(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        setTlCaps(new DesiredCapabilities());
        tlCaps.get().setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 300);
        switch (deviceOS) {
            case "iOS":
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("deviceName", props.getProperty("ios.capability.deviceName"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("udid", props.getProperty("ios.capability.udid"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("platformName", props.getProperty("ios.capability.platformName"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("platformVersion", props.getProperty("ios.capability.platformVersion"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("automationName", props.getProperty("ios.capability.automationName"));
                
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("app", props.getProperty("ios.capability.app"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("includeSafariInWebviews", true);
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("webviewConnectTimeout", 20000);
                break;

            case "Android":
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("deviceName", props.getProperty("android.capability.deviceName"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("udid", props.getProperty("android.capability.udid"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("platformName", props.getProperty("android.capability.platformName"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("platformVersion", props.getProperty("android.capability.platformVersion"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("automationName", props.getProperty("android.capability.automationName"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("unlockType", props.getProperty("android.capability.unlockType"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("unlockKey", props.getProperty("android.capability.unlockKey"));

                tlCaps.get().setCapability("app", props.getProperty("android.capability.app"));
                tlCaps.get().setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
                break;

            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("No or invalid device OS given");
        }

        return getTLCaps();
    }
}
```

ThreadLocalDriver.java

```java
public class ThreadLocalDriver {

    private static final ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> tlDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public static synchronized void setTLDriver(AppiumDriver driver) { tlDriver.set(driver); }
    public static synchronized AppiumDriver getTLDriver() {
        return tlDriver.get();
    }
}
```

testng.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Automation Test" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

    <test name="iOS">
        <parameter name="deviceOS" value="iOS"/>
        <parameter name="cucumber.filter.tags" value="(@ios or not @android) and not (@skip or @demo)"/>
        <parameter name="cucumber.plugin" value="pretty, json:target/cucumber-reports_ios/test_results.json,
        junit:target/cucumber-reports_ios/test_results.xml,
        html:target/cucumber-reports_ios/test_results.html"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="runner.RunParallelTests"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Android">
        <parameter name="deviceOS" value="Android"/>
        <parameter name="cucumber.filter.tags" value="(@android or not @ios) and not (@skip or @demo)"/>
        <parameter name="cucumber.plugin" value="pretty, json:target/cucumber-reports_android/test_results.json,
        junit:target/cucumber-reports_android/test_results.xml,
        html:target/cucumber-reports_android/test_results.html"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="runner.RunParallelTests"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    
</suite>
```

From there it is your basic POM cucumber step up. I do initialize all my Page Objects at the top of my `StepDefs.java` file `protected PageObject pageObject = new PageObject(ThreadLocalDriver.getTLDriver())` but I plan to move them into a thread safe factory class eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's you should collect logs of when these errors happen, or give steps to reproduce this error so people can try to figure out why exactly this error happens in your situation.